# In C++, how does the system associate each of these objects with the window in which the program is executed?

Tags: c++

Essentially, I am learning C++. Anyways, I have bought this book called C++ Primer 5th Edition, and in the first unit, when learning about istream and outstream, I came across this statement,

> "Ordinarily, the system associates each of these objects with the window in which the program is executed."

Can someone please explain what this means, and how the system does this.

Comment: You run a program from a window, its output and input comes from that window. Nothing to see here, move along. The End.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast, however I don't really understand what they mean by window.

Comment: Actually, there are a *lot* of software layers in between. If you are curious, read about [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [display servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server).

Comment: If you don't understand what a window is, how exactly did you post your question on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Do they mean instances of the program? I am sorry for my confusion, it's just that I don't understand the concept.

Comment: Yes, they probably mean *processes*, and I find the book quite bad (not every valid C++ implementation runs in a window).

Comment: Alright well thank you, I was recommended this book by StackOverFlow itself. If you could, can you please recommend a better one?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I find the book really good.  The context of this sentence is a console window.

Comment: I *think* they mean: if you have multiple console windows opened (cmd.exe) and you run one and the same program in each console, each program has its own std::cout, std::cin and std::cerr and each program reads from/writes to exactly the console (== the window) it was started from...

Comment: Or linux shell... But if meant so, this is really ***poor*** wording...

Comment: C++ doesn't have a notion about a _window_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your book is wrong, or at least very simplifying. For example, you could compile and run valid and standard C++ code on a Linux server (that you have rented from some VPS provider) or a supercomputer and such a server has no screens and no windows. And the C++ code (compiled) that you use on servers running in datacenters at Google or Facebook (probably the most common computations you do) has no "windows".

Or you could cross-compile some C++ code for a small microcontroller like an [arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) which has no screens and no windows.

Then, even if you assume to compile then run some C++ code on a laptop (running an ordinary operating system like Linux, Window, MacOSX, Android....) there are *many layers* of software involved (cumulating many millions of lines of code).

If you want to understand more, read about [display servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server), [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator), [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) and about [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system).

You C++ implementation gives you (thru its C++ standard library and many other layers of software) the abstraction of console streams. How these are really implemented is a complex topic. Windows are unknown to the C++14 standard (but consider using a complex GUI framework library like [Qt](http://qt.io/) if you need some).

If you have access to some Linux system, try to [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) a hello-world program in C++ and read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page; you'll be surprised by the amounts of system calls involved (and your *terminal emulator* is much more complex than hello-world, and so is the display server).

<sup>PS. At Paris 6 university, an full-year course (of several hours per week) is required to explain only the *basics* of the answer to your question</sup>

Comment: So for example, if I were to run a simple program, instead of there being one window or one process, many windows would be running in the background. And if for example, I ran some C++ code on a microcontroller, even without a window, the code would still work?

Comment: To be fair to the book.  The context of this sentence is executing it in a shell.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Makes it a *little* better - but still not very precise...

Comment: @Aconcagua It is in the very introductory chapter. Preciseness is not high on the list,  when you just want to get started.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Perhaps - but bad wording can lead to confusion - the question would not exist if not...

Comment: "Ordinarily", C++ code does not run in the situations you describe.  The textbook starts its explanation with that word.  So, I'm not sure why you are stating the textbook is wrong?

Comment: I'm not so sure. Are you sure that most of the C++ code you are using is not running on some (remote) internet or back-end server.... Most people use more computing power from datacenters (e.g. Google & Facebook) than locally on their laptop/tablet.

Answer (score 3):

Magic.

No, I'm serious.  The C++ standard dictates that the compiler needs to provide a certian environment to the C++ program.  This environment is rather abstract -- it is called the abstract machine.

Specific compilers decide to attach that abstract machine to particular behaviors on the actual machine they run on.  How this happens is *outside* the C++ language.

In practice, what happens is that a given C++ executable is compiled to run in a given operating system (and usually on given kinds of compatible hardware).

The operating system knows how to *load* your executable into memory, and "wires up" the parts of the executable to its own services (or directly to hardware services) that provide features, like console output/input, memory allocation, threading, etc etc etc.

The compiler was written with the ability to write that executable in mind.  The operating system was written with the ability to load that executable in mind.

In some cases, the "operating system" is firmware on a chip or motherboard, and "loading the executable" consists of initializing a ROM with the bits that come out of the compiler.

In more common cases, the "operating system" is a modern desktop operating system.  It specifies an executable layout, and provides ways for such an executable to talk to the OS/kernel/screen/etc.

The compiler could have libraries (dynamic or not) that are written to help the program interact with the operating system of your computer, which it links to your program implicitly.

The operating system itself is going to be written, usually, in a mixture of machine code, assembly and higher level languages (like C, C++ or even Java).  It will often be running in a "different mode" than client code is running in, and have access to a very different environment.

In short, Magic.

C++ does not specify how this happens, it just demands the compiler do it.  These things are usually not fully implemented in C++.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the process in such a beginner-friendly manner!